# ODBC connection in R with Azure Active Directory Password authentication

Tags: r, sql-server, azure-active-directory, odbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL server from R and I'm using the Azure Active Directory Password authentication. My connection in R define as follow :

```
ch <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc(),
                        DSN = "myDSN",
                        Database = "dbname",
                        Authentication="ActivedirectoryPassword",
                        UID = uid,
                        PWD = password
        )
```

This is failing by the following error :

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: FA004: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'my_user_id' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').
Error code 0x800401F0; state 10
CoInitialize has not been called.
```

However, when I test the exact same setting on Microsoft SQL Server DSN Configuration, everything is fine and I'm able to connect successfully to the same database :
[image]

Any idea if I'm missing something here ?!

Comment: Seems relevant, [Azure SQL Server Error: CoInitialize has not been called. #343](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/343)

Comment: Tried to connect from Linux machine with R odbc package version 1.3.0 and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server - everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, if I use package `odbc 1.2.3`, it is ok for me.

```
library(odbc)
uid <- ""
pwd <- ""
ch <- odbc::dbConnect(odbc(),
  DSN = "mydsn",
  Database = "xxx",
  Authentication="ActivedirectoryPassword",
  UID = uid,
  PWD = pwd
)
dbListTables(ch)
```

[image]